# Some characters get lost while writing to StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder, zip

Im dealing with Java code and here it is:

```
public InputStream unzip(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
        zipIn.getNextEntry();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(zipIn);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            sb.append(sc.nextLine());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
        zipIn.close();
        InputStream is = fromStringBuffer(sb);
        return (InputStream)is;
    }

    public static InputStream fromStringBuffer(StringBuilder sb) {
          return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());
        }
```

While I am unzipping the file some Turkish characters get in a weird format (like `Ü` becomes `Ãœ`).

How can I have them to be written to StringBuilder correctly?

Comment: try `return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF8"));` and try to make your `InputStream` contain `UTF8` encoding to `unzip`

Comment: Not really to your question, but change `sb.append("\n");` to `sb.append(System.lineSeparator());` - the first form will break on Windows.

Comment: @SunilDabburi that doesnt work

Comment: It's an encoding issue. Set the encoding to UTF-8 in IDE as well as use return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF8"));

Comment: @yarenska If that didn't work out, try changing your scanner to this `Scanner sc = new Scanner(zipIn, "UTF8");`

Comment: Try setting the encoding to `"UTF16"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams (of the `java.io` variety, as opposed to `java.util.stream`) are for reading (or writing) *bytes*.

`Scanner` deals with *chars*. If you pass an `InputStream` to a `Scanner`, you need to provide a charset; otherwise it uses the default charset.

But: this assumes that the byte stream passed to the `Scanner` actually does represent a stream of chars, using some charset. A `ZipInputStream` does not, necessarily: it's whatever the contents of the zipped file are. If you say there are characters missing, I presume your zipped file is text; but, from the perspective of reading from the zip file, it's just a stream of bytes.

If you want an `InputStream` from a `ZipInputStream`, simply return the `ZipInputStream`.

If you want to interpret the returned stream as chars, of course you will still need to know the charset; but you just won't have introduced unnecessary round-tripping from bytes to chars to bytes here.

If you want all of the charset encoding to be handled inside this method, return a [`Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html), the analogue of `InputStream` that represents a stream of chars.

For example, you could return an `InputStreamReader`, e.g. `new InputStreamReader(zipIn, charset)`. This doesn't absolve you of the issues of knowing the correct charset; but it insulates callers of the method from having to deal with it instead.